# convert number of seconds since 1970 to DateTime for a specific time zone?

Tags: c++

I want to convert seconds since 1970 to datetime for a specific time zone.

I have the time in milisecond and the timezone for a server.
I am getting these values by calling an API. I want to know the year,month, day of that time zone.

int milisecond  = 12347586484;
zone = "GMT +8.00";

How can I do that?

Thanks,
Syd

Edit: Will I get the right date if I use gmtime()?

```
timeinmilisecond + 8*360000;

struct tm *jobCreationtm;
time_t t = (time_t)(timeinmilisecond); 
jobCreationtm = gmtime(&t);
```

Note: I dont want to use third party dlls.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio C++?

Comment: yes I am using visual studio C++. But I dont want my code to be windows specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the TZ environment variable to the timezone you want (see the manual page for tzset), and then call localtime.

Something like (now tested):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    ::putenv("TZ=GMT+8");
    time_t t = ::time(0);
    tm* x = ::localtime(&t);
    char buf[1024];
    ::strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z", x);
    std::cout << ::getenv("TZ") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "[" << buf << "]" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
GMT+8
[Thu, 17 Feb 2011 02:22:41 -0800]
```

Answer (score 0):

What format is the timezone from your server? Is it a GMT offset or formatted like "America\Los Angeles". It's tough w/o a 3rd party library because the result is different based time of year (day light savings) and changes with time (certain counties in Midwest for example change from EST to CST every few years).

Consider installing the [ICU library](http://userguide.icu-project.org/datetime/timezone#TOC-Timezone-Class-in-ICU). Given time stamps and a locale (or GMT offset) you can get formatted time / date strings very easily using the [TimeZone](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classTimeZone.html) class.